# Multiple fragments overlap and not hiding on navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation

I have 2 random recurring issues in my application, that currently pop-up in production:

- When the application is resumed/reopened after some time elapsed. It has `fragments` overlapping each other while switching between them.
- When the application is resumed/reopened, the bottom navigation icons do not seem to respond to context switching, even though the fragment loads fine.

Both the above mentioned issues are hard to reproduce locally. I have tried the solution for replacing the fragment However, on the device they do pop up very often now. Here is what my `MainActivity` looks like:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME = "fragment_home"
    private val TAG_FRAGMENT_NEWS = "fragment_news"
    private val TAG_FRAGMENT_MARKET = "fragment_market"
    private val TAG_FRAGMENT_EXPLORE = "fragment_explore"
    private var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView? = null
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    private val marketsFragment = MarketsFragment()
    private val newsFragment = NewsFragment()
    private val exploreFragment = ExploreFragment()

    private lateinit var active: Fragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        bottomNavigationView!!.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            // Set up navigation here
            R.id.home -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
                active = homeFragment
            }
            R.id.news ->{
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(newsFragment).commit()
                active = newsFragment
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.markets -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(marketsFragment).commit()
                active = marketsFragment
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.explore -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(exploreFragment).commit()
                active = exploreFragment
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        active = homeFragment
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        if (!fragmentExists(TAG_FRAGMENT_EXPLORE)) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, exploreFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_EXPLORE).hide(exploreFragment).commit()
        }
        if (!fragmentExists(TAG_FRAGMENT_MARKET)) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, marketsFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_MARKET).hide(marketsFragment).commit()
        }
        if (!fragmentExists(TAG_FRAGMENT_NEWS)) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, newsFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_NEWS).hide(newsFragment).commit()
        }
        if (!fragmentExists(TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME)) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,homeFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_HOME).commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that when the user reopens the application, `onResume` is called, I am trying to add only those fragments that are not already added. Also, I am using `add` instead of `replace` as I want eager loading instead of lazy. As I observed that with using `replace fragment`, creation was invoked each time the navigation was switched.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing the implementation and used [this](https://github.com/Atr07/drawer-with-bottom-navigation-architecture) instead. For anyone stumbling upon this weird issue and is using `supportFragmentManager`, give this a chance. It is using `navgraph` for `navigation` between fragments. Looks like it is the recommended way of doing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Met the bug when I overwritten bottom navigation `onItemSelected` and `onItemReselected` methods, because of issue with relaunching botNav menu fragments and some additional navigation behaviour. So whether it's your case, try to remove overwritten `onItemSelected` or be careful using `popBackStack` and `navigate`, and in `onItemReselected` use `navController.popBackStack(itemId, false)`.

It helped in my case and may help you too.

Thanks.